# How to reformat dataframe in order to calculate basic values (mean, SD, SE, etc.) in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, formattable

I have a dataframe called 'my_data' that looks like so:

```
Injury         BL.Time.Delay Acute.Time.Delay Chronic.Time.Delay Acute.Area.Def Chronic.Area.Def BL.BBB Acute.BBB Chronic.BBB
1  Moderate          0.35             1.10               0.60           1.84            0.150     21        11          18
2    Severe          0.42             1.47               0.86           3.04            0.420     21         3          14
3  Moderate          0.45             1.02               0.65           1.80            0.150     21        11          18
4  Moderate          0.42             0.97               0.70           1.76            0.000     21         8          17
5    Severe          0.40             1.55               0.80           3.12            0.370     21         4          11
6  Moderate          0.37             0.96               0.65           1.65            0.240     21         9          14
7    Severe          0.32             1.64               0.75           3.34            0.400     21         2          12
8    Severe          0.40             1.44               0.90           3.24            0.298     21         1           9
9  Moderate          0.47             1.01               0.82           1.77            0.140     21         7          17
10 Moderate          0.41             0.90               0.67           1.51            0.190     21         9          15
11 Moderate          0.38             0.86               0.57           1.78            0.100     21        10          17
12   Severe          0.39             1.59               0.70           3.27            0.360     21         2          12
```

I would like to format the Injury factors (Moderate and Severe) to columns with its assocaited measurement per column (time delay, area deficit, etc). There are also three time points (BL, Acute, Chronic) which I would also like to factor into my final dataframe.

I ran this code for basic stats but it is not grouped by injury group (Moderate vs Severe)

```
updated_df <- sapply(my_data[, c(2:9)], function(my_data) c("Mean"= mean(my_data,na.rm=TRUE),
                          "Stand dev" = sd(my_data),
                          "Stand Err" = sd(my_data)/sqrt(length(my_data)),
                         "Median" = median(my_data),
                         "CoeffofVariation" = sd(my_data)/mean(my_data,na.rm=TRUE),
                         "Minimum" = min(my_data),
                         "Maximun" = max(my_data),
                         "Upper Quantile" = quantile(my_data,.75),
                         "LowerQuartile" = quantile(my_data,.25),
                         "n" = length(my_data)
)
)
```

How to run the statistics shown above and group by Injury Type (Mod vs Sev) with time points factored in?

Comment: `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` should be able to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WIth the current set up, an option is to `split` by 'Injury Type', loop over the `list` with `lapply` and  apply the code

```
lst1 <- split(my_data, my_data$Injury, drop = TRUE)
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(dat) 
     sapply(dat[, 2:9], function(my_data1)  c("Mean"= mean(my_data1,na.rm=TRUE),
                      "Stand dev" = sd(my_data1),
                      "Stand Err" = sd(my_data1)/sqrt(length(my_data1)),
                     "Median" = median(my_data1),
                     "CoeffofVariation" = sd(my_data1)/mean(my_data1,na.rm=TRUE),
                     "Minimum" = min(my_data1),
                     "Maximun" = max(my_data1),
                     "Upper Quantile" = quantile(my_data1,.75),
                     "LowerQuartile" = quantile(my_data1,.25),
                     "n" = length(my_data1))))
```

-output

```
lst2
#$Moderate
#                       BL.Time.Delay Acute.Time.Delay Chronic.Time.Delay Acute.Area.Def Chronic.Area.Def BL.BBB
#    Mean                  0.40714286       0.97428571         0.66571429     1.73000000       0.13857143     21
#    Stand dev             0.04347961       0.07955232         0.08059304     0.11313708       0.07515064      0
#    Stand Err             0.01643375       0.03006795         0.03046131     0.04276180       0.02840427      0
#    Median                0.41000000       0.97000000         0.65000000     1.77000000       0.15000000     21
#    CoeffofVariation      0.10679202       0.08165194         0.12106251     0.06539716       0.54232422      0
#    Minimum               0.35000000       0.86000000         0.57000000     1.51000000       0.00000000     21
#    Maximun               0.47000000       1.10000000         0.82000000     1.84000000       0.24000000     21
#    Upper Quantile.75%    0.43500000       1.01500000         0.68500000     1.79000000       0.17000000     21
#    LowerQuartile.25%     0.37500000       0.93000000         0.62500000     1.70500000       0.12000000     21
#    n                     7.00000000       7.00000000         7.00000000     7.00000000       7.00000000      7
#                        Acute.BBB Chronic.BBB
#    Mean                9.2857143  16.5714286
#    Stand dev           1.4960265   1.5118579
#    Stand Err           0.5654449   0.5714286
#    Median              9.0000000  17.0000000
#    CoeffofVariation    0.1611105   0.0912328
#    Minimum             7.0000000  14.0000000
#    Maximun            11.0000000  18.0000000
#    Upper Quantile.75% 10.5000000  17.5000000
#    LowerQuartile.25%   8.5000000  16.0000000
#    n                   7.0000000   7.0000000

#    $Severe
#                       BL.Time.Delay Acute.Time.Delay Chronic.Time.Delay Acute.Area.Def Chronic.Area.Def BL.BBB
#    Mean                  0.38600000       1.53800000         0.80200000     3.20200000       0.36960000     21
#    Stand dev             0.03847077       0.08288546         0.08074652     0.12049896       0.04659184      0
#    Stand Err             0.01720465       0.03706751         0.03611094     0.05388877       0.02083651      0
#    Median                0.40000000       1.55000000         0.80000000     3.24000000       0.37000000     21
#    CoeffofVariation      0.09966520       0.05389172         0.10068144     0.03763241       0.12606019      0
#    Minimum               0.32000000       1.44000000         0.70000000     3.04000000       0.29800000     21
#    Maximun               0.42000000       1.64000000         0.90000000     3.34000000       0.42000000     21
#    Upper Quantile.75%    0.40000000       1.59000000         0.86000000     3.27000000       0.40000000     21
#    LowerQuartile.25%     0.39000000       1.47000000         0.75000000     3.12000000       0.36000000     21
#    n                     5.00000000       5.00000000         5.00000000     5.00000000       5.00000000      5
#                       Acute.BBB Chronic.BBB
#    Mean               2.4000000  11.6000000
#    Stand dev          1.1401754   1.8165902
#    Stand Err          0.5099020   0.8124038
#    Median             2.0000000  12.0000000
#    CoeffofVariation   0.4750731   0.1566026
#    Minimum            1.0000000   9.0000000
#    Maximun            4.0000000  14.0000000
#    Upper Quantile.75% 3.0000000  12.0000000
#    LowerQuartile.25%  2.0000000  11.0000000
#    n                  5.0000000   5.0000000
```

---

We can convert to a single dataset by `rbind`ing

```
out <- do.call(rbind, unname(Map(function(x, y) 
 `row.names<-`(transform(data.frame(Injury = x, y, 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE), rn = row.names(y)), NULL),  names(lst2), lst2)))
```

#### data

```
my_data <- structure(list(Injury = c("Moderate", "Severe", "Moderate", "Moderate", 
"Severe", "Moderate", "Severe", "Severe", "Moderate", "Moderate", 
"Moderate", "Severe"), BL.Time.Delay = c(0.35, 0.42, 0.45, 0.42, 
0.4, 0.37, 0.32, 0.4, 0.47, 0.41, 0.38, 0.39), Acute.Time.Delay = c(1.1, 
1.47, 1.02, 0.97, 1.55, 0.96, 1.64, 1.44, 1.01, 0.9, 0.86, 1.59
), Chronic.Time.Delay = c(0.6, 0.86, 0.65, 0.7, 0.8, 0.65, 0.75, 
0.9, 0.82, 0.67, 0.57, 0.7), Acute.Area.Def = c(1.84, 3.04, 1.8, 
1.76, 3.12, 1.65, 3.34, 3.24, 1.77, 1.51, 1.78, 3.27), Chronic.Area.Def = c(0.15, 
0.42, 0.15, 0, 0.37, 0.24, 0.4, 0.298, 0.14, 0.19, 0.1, 0.36), 
    BL.BBB = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
    21L, 21L), Acute.BBB = c(11L, 3L, 11L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 
    7L, 9L, 10L, 2L), Chronic.BBB = c(18L, 14L, 18L, 17L, 11L, 
    14L, 12L, 9L, 17L, 15L, 17L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Comment: Okay - Is you dat and my_data1 suppose to be new dataframes? I got an error when applying your code.

Comment: Error: unexpected ')' in:
"                                           "LowerQuartile" = quantile(my_data,.25),
                                           "n" = length(my_data))))"

Comment: @Dinho In your data, I find the column name as 'Injury' and not 'Injury Type'

Comment: @Dinho updated the solution with the data used and the output.  The error was because there was a missing `)`

Comment: Is there anyway to format this into a table or dataframe for imaging purposes?

Comment: @Dinho Do you want a single dataset.  But, then the row names would be duplicated and data.frame doesn't suppor that

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work, and `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` are flexible enough to help you do this with more grouping variables

```
df %>%
  mutate(id = seq_along(Injury)) %>%
  pivot_longer(BL.Time.Delay:Chronic.BBB, names_to = "var", values_to = "value") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, var), names_from = Injury, values_from = value) %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  summarise(Moderate = mean(Moderate, na.rm = T),
            Severe = mean(Severe, na.rm = T))
```

Alternatively, this will give you your output in a longer format

```
df %>%
  mutate(id = seq_along(Injury)) %>%
  pivot_longer(BL.Time.Delay:Chronic.BBB, names_to = "var", values_to = "value") %>%
  # pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, var), names_from = Injury, values_from = value) %>%
  group_by(var, Injury) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: This is also really helpful to see it in a different approach. Thank you! I can add other metrics under summarise as well I'm assuming?